# How to modify camera parameters before capturing each frame?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, camera, android-camera2

I am trying to write a camera app that will create videos with different effects. In order to achieve this, I need to capture each frame with different camera sensor parameters, such as different exposure and different while balance settings. I am aware of the camera2 API in android, which allow us to set the white balance and exposure setting before launching the camera object. However, I wanted to change these setting before each frame is captured by the sensor in video mode. Or in other words, next frame should be captured only after a set of sensor parameters are updated with the latest values.

For example:
In video mode that is set to 20fps

1. Frame 1 should be captured with Exposure value of X1 and White Balance value of X2
2. Frame 2 should be captured with Exposure value of X3 and White Balance value of X4
   and so on.

Post processing the frame after capture with fixed setting is not an option for me; So, I need to change set of sensor parameters before each frame capture (triggered capture with frame readout event). I can try to capture the images with different sensor parameters and process them one by one to build a video stream is also an option. However, it leads to very low frame rate of the end resulted video.

Assume the camera supports all of the above settings...

So, please can any one provide me example or documents or resources that can point me in right direction to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `raspberry-pi` please?

Comment: I think you can try to have two capture request having different request values and then call burst repeating request.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession#setRepeatingBurst(java.util.List%3Candroid.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest%3E,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback,%20android.os.Handler)

Comment: @MarkSetchell raspberry-pi can run Android OS; so I am trying to keep my options open on SBC and OS.

Comment: @WasimAnsari This is the implementation I am looking forward to. I will try this solution. However, the framerate would be less, I guess.

Comment: @lokesh , Yes it will impacted as you will  change exposure settings as well.